# How to read an image file to a byte[]?

Tags: c#, file-io

This is how I save images.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension;
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Photos"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        //...
    }
}
```

I don't want to display the image from that location. I want rather to read it first for further processing.

How do I read the image file in that case?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what format you expect it to be in?  e.g. a Stream, or maybe something else?

Comment: There is no question here.  Questions end with a question mark (?).

Comment: @abelenky: I added a question.

Comment: It's still unclear, since 'read' has multiple interpretations. What is the purpose of reading it? I posted an answer on how to 'read' it by loading it as a BitMap instance, which can be used for pixel processing. If you would rather want to 'read' it by processing the raw binary, then you would use a Stream.

Comment: @harvadu: You are right, I'm not enough explicit. This is what I'm trying to do. Since file upload HTML element doesn't keep the file uploaded, I need a temporary storage to keep the image uploaded. That's why I save those files to "Conte/Photos" location so they can be displayed to the user. Once the user has decided to save, I need to save them to the database and clear the temporary storage.

Comment: I will update my answer to reflect how you can load a saved image into a byte[], assuming that's what you need to get it into the database.

Comment: @harvadu: Yes, I want to save them to database.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Update: Reading the image to a byte[]

```
// Load file meta data with FileInfo
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

// The byte[] to save the data in
byte[] data = new byte[fileInfo.Length];

// Load a filestream and put its content into the byte[]
using (FileStream fs = fileInfo.OpenRead())
{
    fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}

// Delete the temporary file
fileInfo.Delete();

// Post byte[] to database
```

*For history's sake, here's my answer before the question was clarified.*

Do you mean loading it as a [BitMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx) instance?

```
 BitMap image = new BitMap(path);

 // Do some processing
 for(int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
 {
     for(int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
     {
         Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
         Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0);
         image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
     }
 }

// Save it again with a different name
image.Save(newPath);
```

Comment: Let's me ask you another question just to learn more. because of the way you processed the FileInfo, should I say that FileInfo has the same nature as HttpPostedFileBase?

Comment: No, they serve different purposes. FileInfo 'provides properties and instance methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of files, and aids in the creation of FileStream objects.', but HttpPostedFileBase is a wrapper around binary data uploaded from the web - 'Encapsulates the HTTP intrinsic object that provides access to individual files that have been uploaded by a client.' They have a couple of things in common, though.