# How to send JPG over TCP from one Windows Phone to another? I already managed sending text

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, jpeg

How to send JPG over TCP from one Windows Phone to another?

I found that in the other SO topic(below) showing how to send text over TCP, **but how to turn JPG to bytes and send it?** Most of jpges are bigger than 4kb how to deal with that?:

```
private void sendMessage() {
    connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs { RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(localIP, Int32.Parse(port)) };
    connectArgs.Completed += connectArgs_Completed;
    connection = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    connection.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);
}

void connectArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success && firstLoop) {
        firstLoop = false;
        var sendArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MESSAGE STRING" + Environment.NewLine);
        sendArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        sendArgs.Completed += sendArgs_Completed;
        e.ConnectSocket.SendAsync(sendArgs);
    } else {
        //blad
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably [read the raw image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296534/read-an-image-file) and send that, along with a special "code" or prefix, and then on the receiving end, save the raw image data to a .jpg file and display that. You can do that with any file.

Comment: But how to split that image so it fits the `var buffer `? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

TCP doesn't limit the size of the packets to 4KB, so that shouldn't be a problem for you. You simply need to read all the image bytes either from file using `File.ReadAllBytes` or a stream reader, and you then send those bytes across to the receiver.

Alternatively, if you have the image as an object, you could use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` on the sending end and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to re-create the image object from the bytes you have received, if you want to show the image directly for example.

Comment: Yes I would like to show the image directly, load it to: `        <Image x:Name="imagePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="575" Margin="12,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458"/>
`
Could you pleeeeeeaaaase provide an example.

Comment: You could treat the TCP data as a stream (because it really is a stream) and then create an image from stream http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx